# Is there some kind of service that can turn Jquery code into pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, service

Im using jQuery for couple of selectors and little things and just wondering, since it could be really healthy for page load time.

Comment: jquery load should not take much time. Coupled with caching enabled for js resource it literally goes down tremendously.

Comment: If all you want is selectors, jQuery makes its Sizzle selector engine available as a stand alone library. It's a fraction of the size of jQuery. https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/tree/master

Comment: Awesome! Sizzle is only 20kb in size. I should really think about that! Thank you Clayton!

Answer (score 2):

I don't thing there is anything like that. jQuery is not a different language - it's really just a framework for JavaScript. That is in contrast to TypeScript vs Javascript where the former is a higher-level language that can be compiled to Javascript.

But if your code is just very simple jQuery then you should be able to manually re-write the same code without using JavaScript.

However unless you have good data to show you that including jQuery is a bottleneck for you I wouldn't worry about it too much.